# C# adding string to list, one by one, updating displayed list each time

Tags: c#, list, windows-forms-designer

My endgame is to be able to input words into a text box one by one and have them appear in an updated, alphabetical list, every time I enter a code. I'm fairly new at this so sorry for any mistakes!

```
namespace SortWords2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = String.Empty;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string newWord;
        newWord = textBox1.Text;
        addToList(newWord);
    }

    public  void addToList(string word)
    {
        List<string> inputList = new List<string>();
        inputList.Add(word);
        inputList.Sort();
        foreach(string words in inputList)
        {
            label1.Text += "\r\n" + words;
        }
    }
}
}
```

In this current state it just adds the input word, then skips to the next line for me to add another word. So I'm not even sure if I am making a list, I think its just adding the current word.

Comment: Your list is local to method addToList(string word), so each time you click the button you create a new list and that is why you are only seeing the inputted word. You need to create a list that has scope for the entire class. I'll post example below.

Comment: What do you think this does?  `List<string> inputList = new List<string>();`

Comment: Also, `newWord = textBox1.Text;` if you can assign something to a var without some sort of conversion, then *they are the same data type*.  There is no need to create that temp var.

Answer (score 2):

Create a private list for your class like so, and in button click add new string to your private list:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Declare private list of type string as class property, this maintains
    //scope in all methods of class object
    private List<string> inputList;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = String.Empty;
        //Initialize your list
        this.inputList = new List<string>();
    }
```

Now in your button click method:

```
public  void addToList(string word)
    {
        //Remove this next line as you are appending to your class's list
        //and you initialized it in your constructor
        //List<string> inputList = new List<string>();
        inputList.Add(word);
        inputList.Sort();
        foreach(string words in inputList)
        {
            label1.Text += "\r\n" + words;
        }

        //If you really want to get funky, you can do the linq llambda way of appending to your label
       //inputList.ForEach(x => label1.Text += "\r\n" + x);
    }
```

Comment: It works! Thank you So much! I used your code and it was adding a whole updated list to my output so I simply added a label1.Text = String.Empty; at the beginning of the button click! You guys/gals are rockstars.

Comment: @eran0801 Glad it helped. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
//this exists at the **class** level, outside of a function
private List<string> inputList = new List<string>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    addToList(textBox1.Text);
}

public  void addToList(string word)
{
    inputList.Add(word);
    inputList.Sort();

    label1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, inputList);
}
```

Comment: Sorry new here, but since my question has been answered do I need to close out the question or something?

Comment: If the other answer worked for you, mark it as accepted. You got two answers because I started mine just as @RyanWilson was posting his, and I had to take a phone call in the middle so I didn't finish right away.

Comment: @eran0801 BTW: how do you want to handle duplicate words? Are we assuming that just won't happen, do you want to filter them, or do you want to allow them?

Comment: I never thought of that. It wasn't something that I had to do, would I have to do some sort of 'for' loop to compare each word entered to the rest of the words on the list?

Comment: No. If you need to worry about duplicate words you would use a `HashSet<string>` instead of a `List<string>`.